# Makefile dependency file error when including it

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am finding problem when I try to include a C source file in my Makefile. This C source file contains a function which is called by the C++ code (list.cpp) through external C linkage option. I would like to know which is the right place in the Makefile to include this C source code whose function is invoked inside C++ code. If I try adding this C file in the Makefile's SOURCES variable in order to built it, then the C++ code fails to correctly resolve the function call of C and I am getting *linker error: undefined reference*

Following is my Makefile content:

```
CFLAGS =-c -g -Wall -std=c++11
SOURCES = list.cpp
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXEC = a.out

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    @$(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ && $(EXEC)

.cpp.o:
    @$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the C source file that you need in the build is `bar.c`,
and that it has an associated header file `bar.h` that you are
`#include`-ing in `list.cpp`, and that you have correctly coded the `extern C` 
boilerplate in `bar.h`.

Then the following makefile will do what you need:

**Makefile**

```
CXX_SOURCES := list.cpp
C_SOURCES := bar.c
OBJECTS = $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o) $(CXX_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

CXXFLAGS := -g -Wall -std=c++11
CFLAGS := -g -Wall
CPPFLAGS :=
LDFLAGS :=
LDLIBS :=
EXEC := a.out

.PHONY: all clean test

all: $(EXEC)

test: $(EXEC)
    ./$<

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)

list.o: bar.h

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) *.o
```

There are a lot of learning-points here:

**1.** Use immediate evaluation (`:=`) rather than recursive evaluation (`=`) of
make variables unless you particularly want recursive evaluation. See
[6.2 The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html)

**2.** If a target is merely a name for a task and not the name of a file that
the task will create, then it's a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)
and you should tell `make` that it is a phony target, like:

```
.PHONY: all clean test
```

**3.** It is not normal for the make-recipe that builds a program to *run* the program as
well, like your:

```
@$(CXX) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ && $(EXEC)
```

You don't always want to run a program just because you've built it, and
if the program is a long-running or interactive one then this approach
will make it impractial to *build* the program at all.

Probably, you want to run the program to *test* that it has been built correctly.
But building is one task, testing is another (that may take much longer and
involve additional resources); so you should provide a separate phony target
for testing. I've called it `test` in this makefile: often it is called `check`.
To build the program without testing it, just run `make`. To test it,
run `make test` - and this will *also* (re)build the program *if it needs to be (re)built*.

**4.** You don't need to write a rule to make `name.o` from a `name.cpp`, or
a rule to make `name.o` from a `name.c`. GNU `make` has [builtin rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) for doing
this correctly, as long as you have correctly set the make-variables that
`make` uses in those builtin rules:

- `CC`:         The command that invokes C compilation or linkage, e.g. `gcc`
- `CXX`:        The command that invokes C++ compilation or linkage, e.g. `g++`
- `CFLAGS`:     Options for C compilation
- `CXXFLAGS`:   Options for C++ compilation
- `CPPFLAGS`:   Options for the C/C++ preprocessor

**5.** Two more important make-variables that have conventional meanings are:

- `LDFLAGS`:    Options for linkage, excluding library (`-l`) options
- `LDLIBS`:     Library options (`-l`) for linkage.

In the simple makefile above, `CPPFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` and `LDLIBS` are not
needed and could be ommitted. Instead, I've assigned them empty values
just to illustrate their use.

**6.** A makefile should have a phony target `clean` that deletes any files
that the makefile might have created, so that `make clean` gets you
ready to build anything or everything from scratch.

**7.**. If `name.o` is compiled from `name.c` or `name.cpp`, then of
course `name.o` depends on `name.c`|`name.cpp`, but it *also depends
on every header file that is included by* `name.c`|`name.cpp`, and the
makefile needs to express all those dependencies to work reliably. So
in this case you need (at least) the rule:

```
list.o: bar.h
```

so that if you change `bar.h` then `make` will see that `foo.o` is out of
date and will carry out its recipe for re-making `foo.o`. When you
start building complex programs it will become impractical for you
to figure out all these header-file dependencies yourself: then you'll need
to find out about *auto dependency generation*.

Here is [the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)